# Cant cast data to action params in jquery ajax - ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this Action in mvc like this :

```
  [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult AddAttachment(Guid scheduleId, DropZoneResultViewModel file2)
    {
       // do something here
        return Json(true);

    }
```

and I have this js code :

```
var _data = {
        scheduleId: '2867dc39-5455-10e6-4e6f-7ea197bc2f22',
        file2: {
            FileName: '12.jpg',
            OriginalFileName: '1245',
            FileSize: 12454,
            ContentType: 'image/exe',
            FileExtension: '.exe'
        }


    };


    $.ajax({
        url: addattachmneturl,
        data: JSON.stringify( _data),
                type: 'POST',
                suucess: function (data) {
                    alert('yes , you can ');
        },
                error: function (response) {
        }
    });
```

but it returns this error message :

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'scheduleId' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid'

and a result of _data is :

```
{"scheduleId":"2867dc39-5455-10e6-4e6f-7ea197bc2f22","file2":{"FileName":"12.jpg","OriginalFileName":"1245","FileSize":12454,"ContentType":"image/exe","FileExtension":".exe"}}:""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the request payload -

```
var _data = {
    scheduleId: '2867dc39-5455-10e6-4e6f-7ea197bc2f22',
    file2: {
        FileName: '12.jpg',
        OriginalFileName: '1245',
        FileSize: 12454,
        ContentType: 'image/exe',
        FileExtension: '.exe'
    }
};
```

I would expect the `AddAttachment` action should look like the follwing -

```
public virtual ActionResult AddAttachment(PayLoad _data){}
```

where `PayLoad` is -

```
public class PayLoad{
    public Guid scheduleId{get; set ;}
    public  DropZoneResultViewModel file2{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Glad that it helps.